# How to correctly place svg marker on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

I have a svg marker and want to place it on google maps via javascript api.

The problem is that marker is misaligned when I zoom out the map.

This is my svg path:

> M20,13.8c0,5.5-4.4,9.3-10,14.2C4.4,23.1,0,19.3,0,13.8C0,8.4,4.5,4,10,4S20,8.4,20,13.8z

```
  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.788303, -118.001511),
    icon: {
      path: "M20,13.8c0,5.5-4.4,9.3-10,14.2C4.4,23.1,0,19.3,0,13.8C0,8.4,4.5,4,10,4S20,8.4,20,13.8z",
      fillColor: '#1193c5',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black'
    }
  });
```

From what I've already researched I need to set an anchor for the marker but I have no idea how to find anchor point for this svg path.

Here is a working example: https://jsbin.com/gonehocafu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

It is calculable if you know the size of the icon. The path origin for your icon is the upper left hand corner, to get to the middle of the bottom, set x equal to 1/2 the width of the icon, y equal the height of the icon.  For a [SVG symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol):

> **anchor** | Type:  Point
> The position of the symbol relative to the marker or polyline. The coordinates of the symbol's path are translated left and up by the anchor's x and y coordinates respectively. By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.

I usually use trial and error.  For your icon looks like what works is:

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 27)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72vno9kd/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.788303, -118.001511),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.788303, -118.001511),
    icon: {
      path: "M20,13.8c0,5.5-4.4,9.3-10,14.2C4.4,23.1,0,19.3,0,13.8C0,8.4,4.5,4,10,4S20,8.4,20,13.8z",
      fillColor: '#1193c5',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 27)
    },
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```